# Select top 5 records of each group in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to fetch a grouped result, with only top 5 rows for each group.. Confused how to do it..

Here's the query:

```
SELECT O.rest_brId as BRID, O.`reason` as REASON , count(O.reason) as 
OCCURENCES 
FROM orders O 
WHERE O.status = 4 
GROUP BY BRID, REASON 
HAVING count(O.reason)
```

There current result is :
[image: result]

What I want is that every BRID to have <= 5 rows, with TOP 5 MAX no. of OCCURENCES

How to do? Googled, but got confused.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment but would you not need to `ORDER BY OCCURENCES DESC` and then `LIMIT 5`?

Comment: That is not how you can a top n per group.. top n per group requires a co-related subquery with a COUNT(*) or MySQL user variable to simulate a ROW_NUMBER() within a group.. MySQL 8 can use the window function  ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: then apologies, I've misunderstood the question in hand - I thought the poster was asking to limit the result to the top 5 reasons per `BRID` by the amount of occurances